# How to set order invoice number and description in auth Only Continue Transaction type?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, authorize.net

How to update the invoice number and description using Paypal express checkout in AuthorizeNet, with the Transaction type "authOnlyContinueTransaction" or "authCaptureContinueTransaction". Need this to be done in PHP.

I tried the code below :

```
$merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCode\Constants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCode\Constants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);

    // Set the transaction's refId
    $refId = 'ref' . time();

    // Set PayPal compatible merchant credentials
    $paypal_type = new AnetAPI\PayPalType();
    $paypal_type->setPayerID($payerId);

    $paypal_type->setSuccessUrl("http://www.merchanteCommerceSite.com/Success/TC25262");
    $paypal_type->setCancelUrl("http://www.merchanteCommerceSite.com/Success/TC25262");

    $payment_type = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
    $payment_type->setPayPal($paypal_type);

    // Order info
    $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
    $order->setInvoiceNumber("101");
    $order->setDescription("Shirts");

    //create a transaction
    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authOnlyContinueTransaction");
    $transactionRequestType->setRefTransId($transactionId);
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount(4.34);
    $transactionRequestType->setPayment($payment_type);
    $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order);

    $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId($refId);
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);

    $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);

    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

    if ($response != null) {
        if ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == \SampleCode\Constants::RESPONSE_OK) {
            $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();

            if ($tresponse != null && $tresponse->getMessages() != null) {
                echo " Transaction Response code : " . $tresponse->getResponseCode() . "\n";
                echo "TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
                echo "Payer ID : " . $tresponse->getSecureAcceptance()->getPayerID();
                echo "Description : " . $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getDescription() . "\n";
            } else {
                echo "Transaction Failed \n";
                if ($tresponse->getErrors() != null) {
                    echo " Error code  : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode() . "\n";
                    echo " Error message : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText() . "\n";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Transaction Failed \n";
            $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
            if ($tresponse != null && $tresponse->getErrors() != null) {
                echo " Error code  : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode() . "\n";
                echo " Error message : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText() . "\n";
            } else {
                echo " Error code  : " . $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getCode() . "\n";
                echo " Error message : " . $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getText() . "\n";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo  "No response returned \n";
    }
```

Unable to change invoice number and description of orders.
Earlier, with the Transaction type "authOnlyTransaction" or "authCaptureTransaction" was able to update the invoice number and the description.

How to update the same with transaction type is "authOnlyContinueTransaction" or "authCaptureContinueTransaction"?

I referred from https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#PayPal-express-checkout

Comment: Are you getting any errors with this code, please share if any.

Comment: No Not getting any error. 
https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#PayPal-express-checkout. return transaction message type is 
array (
        0 => 
        net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionResponseType\MessagesAType\MessageAType::__set_state(array(
           'code' => '1',
           'description' => 'This transaction has been approved.',
        )),
      ),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the flow. You cannot pass **order** object in *authOnlyContinueTransaction* or *authCaptureContinueTransaction*. The flow is like this.

1. Create a transaction and get the reference id
2. Pass the referenced id in the aforesaid methods to confirm it

Or, better use `createTransactionRequest` that would allow you set the order.

Comment: thanks for  support. but @Rajesh createTransactionRequest always call when send request from any events like Authorization Only, Authorization and Capture, Get Details, Authorization Only Continued etc. when createTransactionResponse call for response. means that createTransactionRequest for request and createTransactionResponse for response.

Comment: Am not saying the expressCheckout method but this one here https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-credit-card

Comment: @Rajesh is correct, you cannot modify the invoice or description in the follow-on transaction for an AuthOnly or AuthCapture transaction.  This is a limitation in the current API.